# Going to source of a method in ASP classic

Tags: asp-classic

In `VS 2013` have opened an `asp classic` project and for example here is a source code from it:

```
   CASE "WSF_LAST"
       call lastname()
```

I have always clicked `F12` on the method name and it goes to the source code of that method but I have never seen or worked on asp classic project and it does nothing when I `F12` it.
If I do a search-all on `lastname()`  the other thing I find is this:

```
<%sub LastName()%>
                                        <tr> 
                                            <td width="1%" align="right" class="inputboxeslabel" nowrap> Last/Inst Name&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td width="99%"><input type="text" name="PhysicianName" size="20" maxlength="35" value="<%=PN%>"></td>
                                        </tr>
<%END Sub
```

So where is finally the code is coming from?

Answer (score 3):

You've found it... that right there is the Subroutine definition. It's not recommended practice to do it quite like this, but it is what it is. More appropriate to define a function and either Response.Write or return the HTML you see above. Jumping in and out of ASP in the middle of a Sub is difficult to read.

Comment: Ok cool but then where is the data coming from? I was hoping to see some sort of SQL commands somewhere

Comment: What has SQL got to do with it? you're calling the subroutine which you found. It will then display that HTML you have found.

Comment: Somewhere above this sub you should find "PN" as a variable being assigned a value. It looks like whoever wrote this code did not do so in the conventional way: where the name would be provided as an argument. They, instead, appear to be using a variable of global scope. I would _expect_ to find it's assignment above the code, as I wouldn't imagine defining a sub that uses a variable that had not already been assigned.  If your editor supports regular expressions, search UP from this sub for \pn/s?=\

Comment: Janusz, has this been answered? If so please indicate as such.